# sql query to create column names based on source column, which values populated from another column

Tags: sql-server

can someone help guide me into converting the data from source table into my desired result table?

From the source, I want to create new column names, based on the "type's" listed in the source, but the values being used to populate would be from "currency"?  Hope that makes sense.  I have created the result table to display what I am trying to create.

source table

| date | id | type | currency |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20230112 | 1 | comm | usd |
| 20230112 | 1 | exch | usd |
| 20230119 | 2 | comm | usd |
| 20230119 | 2 | exch | gbp |

result table

| date | id | comm cur | exch cur |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20230112 | 1 | usd | usd |
| 20230112 | 2 | usd | gbp |

Comment: Where are `id=2` records in your output table?

Comment: sorry, I fixed result table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select [date], id, 
  max(case when type='comm' then currency end) as Comm_cur,
  max(case when type='exch' then currency end) as Exch_cur
from myTable
group by [date], id;
```

Here is [DBFiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/CTkCprPG)

EDIT: How it works?
If we removed MAX() and GROUP BY:

```
select [date], id, 
  case when [type]='comm' then currency end as Comm_cur,
  case when [type]='exch' then currency end as Exch_cur
from myTable;
```

would give this result:

| date | id | Comm_cur | Exch_cur |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-12 | 1 | usd | *null* |
| 2023-01-12 | 1 | *null* | usd |
| 2023-01-19 | 2 | usd | *null* |
| 2023-01-19 | 2 | *null* | gbp |

If we want to reduce those rows to 1 per Date, id we need a GROUP BY. And a GROUP BY requires that we have an aggregation function for all fields that are not listed in GROUP BY list (Date and Id). MAX() and MIN() are aggregation functions that we could use on a string type and the aggregation wouldn't take NULL into account, just what we need. In other words, we are using MAX() or MIN() just to eliminate NULLs. Thus applying MAX() or MIN() and GROUP BY:

```
select [date], id, 
  MIN(case when [type]='comm' then currency end) as Comm_cur,
  MIN(case when [type]='exch' then currency end) as Exch_cur
from myTable
  group by [date], id;
```

results:

| date | id | Comm_cur | Exch_cur |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-12 | 1 | usd | usd |
| 2023-01-19 | 2 | usd | gbp |

[DBfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/HbWJlqZM)

Comment: thanks.  I'm trying to understand max on strings.  from what I am reading it says something about alphabetical order.  Is this working because when type is not equal to something it returns null.... and max is returning something greater than null?

Comment: @solarissf, it doesn't need to be MAX(). It could be MIN() too. It is there just because we are using GROUP BY and thus we need an aggregation function. If you think about it, we didn't use else part which is NULL by default. So for example, [20230119] for Comm_cur, it is saying select MAX() (or MIN() if you wish) of 'usd' and NULL (when type='comm' it is 'usd' else -'exch'- NULL).  On Exch_cur column, we are checking MAX() of 'gpb' and NULL. To understand it by visualizing, remove MAX() and group by and check the result. MAX() is a 'trick' there to say otherwise to GROUP BY those rows into 1.

Comment: @solarissf, I added some visualization about how it works in edit. I hope it is easier to understand now.

Comment: thank you! this clears up my confusion

Comment: sorry to bring up another question, is it possible to make this dynamic based on another table.  in this example I would have a table that lists.. 'comm', 'exch', and I would want the same results

Comment: @solarissf, no problem, it could be a different table. However, I cannot exactly visualize it, can you edit your question and give sample data or create as a new question and give link please?

Comment: thank you so much... I created another post.  https://stackoverflow.com/q/75314275/1316702

Answer (score 1):

Two quick options.

Conditional Aggregation.  Often more performant and offers more flexibility

```
Select date
      ,id
      ,comm_cur = max( case when [type]='comm' then currency end )
      ,exch_cur = max( case when [type]='exch' then currency end )
 From  YourTable
 Group by date,id
```

PIVOT - comes with some restrictions

```
Select *
 From  YourTable src
 Pivot ( max(currency) for [type] in ([comm],[exch]) ) pvt
```

Comment: thanks John.  what did you amend with my table on original post?  I'm trying to understand what I did wrong.  It looked good in the preview.

Comment: @solarissf added line breaks so tables would present correctly  They were a single line

Comment: thank you, would you mind explaining the use of max?  from what I see on a string, it returns the greatest alphanumeric.  does this work because the other it returns are null?

Comment: @solarissf It is the max value based on the intersection of date ,id and type (comm vs exch) .   Just for fun, run the query without the aggregation and group by Select date ,id ,comm_cur = case when [type]='comm' then currency end ,exch_cur = case when [type]='exch' then currency end  From  YourTable

Comment: @solarissf why ask me?  You accepted another answer