# change query to use dynamic columns based on another table - with conditional aggregation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

I am trying to convert this query to using dynamic columns (from another table).  In this example I want to replace the 2 areas where I have type='comm' and type = 'exch' to be dynamic.  (not hardcoded in this line)
The types will be found in another table.

HERE IS MY ORIGINAL QUERY

```
select [date], id, 
  max(case when type='comm' then currency end) as Comm_cur,
  max(case when type='exch' then currency end) as Exch_cur
from myTable
group by [date], id;
```

HERE IS THE TABLE I WANT TO USE FOR THE 'TYPE'

```
insert into #fm (type) values
        ('comm')
        ,('exch')
```

when I google this concept I get dynamic pivot tables as possible solutions but that doesn't see what I am looking to do.

source table

| date | id | type | currency |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20230112 | 1 | comm | usd |
| 20230112 | 1 | exch | usd |
| 20230119 | 2 | comm | usd |
| 20230119 | 2 | exch | gbp |

result table

| date | id | comm cur | exch cur |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20230112 | 1 | usd | usd |
| 20230112 | 2 | usd | gbp |

any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need dynamic sql for this kind of thing. Search `Dynamic cross tab` on this site and you will find lots of nearly identical questions with solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic columns require Dynamic SQL

Here is a working option that will also filter the source table based on your `#fn`

Note:  If not 2017+, you can replace the `string_agg()` with the `stuff/xml` approach.

**Example**

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = '
Select *
 From  (  
Select A.date
      ,A.id
      ,type = A.type+'' cur''
      ,A.currency
 From YourSourceTable A
 Join #fn B on A.type=B.type
       ) src
 Pivot ( max(currency) for [type] in (' + (select string_agg(quotename(type+' cur'),',') from #fn ) + ') ) pvt
'
Exec(@SQL)
```

**Results**

```
date        id  comm cur    exch cur
2023-01-12  1   usd         usd
2023-01-19  2   usd         gbp
```

Just in case you need the stuff/XML

```
Declare @SQL varchar(max) = '
Select *
 From  (  
Select A.date
      ,A.id
      ,type = A.type+'' cur''
      ,A.currency
 From YourSourceTable A
 Join #fn B on A.type=B.type
       ) src
 Pivot ( max(currency) for [type] in (' + stuff((Select Distinct ',' +quotename(type+' cur') From #fn  For XML Path ('')),1,1,'') + ') ) pvt
'
Exec(@SQL)
```

Comment: thank you @John.  it works!  The line I do not understand is the Pivot line.  string_agg takes all expressions from rows and concats into single string.  quotename, returns unicode string with bracket delimeters.  would you mind explaining what this means in plain english?  basically I see the values of my results are the max(currency), but I don't understand the select statement after that